# How to sort items by parent category when item is assigned to subcategory

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I am trying sort Items by Parent Category when item is assigned to subcategory.

### Tables

sql.Categories
`id`,
`title`,
`parent_id`

sql.Classifieds
`id`,
`title`,
`category_id`

### Code

```php
public function getLatestClassifieldsByParentCategories()
    {
        $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = '0'");
        $result = $query->result();


        foreach ($result as $parent) 
        {   

            $return[$parent->id] = $parent;

            $parent_id = $parent->id;
            $query = $this->db->query("SELECT * FROM categories WHERE parent_id = '$parent_id'"); 

            foreach ($result as $category)
            {
                $return[$parent->id]->category = $category;
                $return[$parent->id]->classifields = $this->cflatest->getClassifieldsLastestByCategory($category->id);
            }      
        }

        return $return;
    }
```

**I found another way to do this what works fine**

Answer (score 0):

Why not running this query?

```
SELECT * FROM classifieds JOIN categories ON classifieds.category_id = categories.id ORDER BY categories.title ASC
```

Comment: I want sort Items by Parent categories, but items is signed to subcategory. 

Category 1 = ParentId = 0
- Subcategory 2 ParentId = 1
--- Item 1 - categoryId = 2
--- Item 2 - categoryId = 2
--- Item 3 - categoryId = 2
- Subcategory 3 ParentId = 1
--- Item 4 - categoryId = 3
--- Item 5 - categoryId = 3

Category 4 - ParentId = 0
- Subcategory 5 - ParentId = 4
--- Item  6 - categoryId = 5
- Subcategory 6 - ParentId = 4
--- Item 7 - categoryId = 6 
--- Item 8 - categoryId = 6

**
Edited couples times cause of comment submitted by only pressed enter